# 401 Unauthorized caused by custom master page

Tags: master-page, 2013, custom-masterpage, 401

just customized a master page for the new SP 2013 Foundation. Deployment, activation etc. works fine (i deploy it using a .wsp built with VS2012) but every time im trying to access my sp-page with the custom master page deployed i receive a 401 unauthorized error. 
My log states the following:

> 401 UNAUTHORIZED on
>   http://xxxxx.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx: start.aspx is
>   anonymously accessible but could not be shown to the user.  The most
>   likely reason for this is that the master page contains a control
>   which requires secure properties from an SPWeb (or other SharePoint
>   object).  A control which requires this type of data must be inside an
>   AjaxDelta.

In SharePoint Designer aren't any permissions listed for the specific master page. The default master pages which are available have permissions listed. If im trying to grant permissions via sharepoint-designer nothing changes. If i look up the Gallery for master pages inside sharepoint i can see the folder which stores my master page. Unfortunately there isn't any master-page inside..

going slowly crazy here..

Comment: Have you recently added any custom controls / web parts?

Comment: I had the same problem recently. Could not find an answer to what was causing it. I've ended up deactivating Minimal Download Strategy feature. If you find a better answer it would be great to know it!

Comment: I get this problem occasionally after adding a user control... Any solution?

Comment: What kind of customizations did you embed in your master page? Most probably, the error (quite explicit -that time!) message tells the truth...

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to turn off the MDS feature.

But check this [link](http://www.sharepointfront.com/unautorized-401-sharepoint-2013-with-a-custom-master-page/) for other solution

Comment: Please do not post answers this dependent on a link. Add more details from the link instead and use the link as a source

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old but I had this issue in SharePoint 2016 and have not seen my solution posted anywhere.

My issue was that I had loaded a custom master page through a solutions file.

To solve the problem, I did the following:

1. In the Site Collection, go into Site Settings --> Master Pages under Web Designer Galleries.
2. Find the HTML file for the Master Page you are using.
3. From the quick menu, select Publish a Major Version

The .master file will automatically be regenerated.